# Classical piece used as hold music on call to local GP

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I heard it while on hold calling my local GP. Very familiar sounding. I tried to Shazam it but didn't work.

[I put the first few notes into the sequencer.](https://onlinesequencer.net/1111071)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the famous "Celebrated" [Minuet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AZOknKotVc), by classical composer Luigi Boccherini, frequently used in movies and on television as a signifier of elegance, class and refinement.  For Suzuki-trained violinists, this piece is the graduation requirement for the second repertory book.

> The **String Quintet in E major, Op. 11, No. 5 (G 275)**, by Luigi Boccherini was written in 1771 and published in 1775. Being one of his most famous works, the quintet is famous for its minuet third movement (often referred to as "The Celebrated Minuet") which is most-often played as a standalone piece outside of the context of the full quintet
>
> [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_Quintet_in_E_major,_Op._11,_No.*5*(Boccherini)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_Quintet_in_E_major,_Op._11,_No._5_(Boccherini))

It also features has a startlingly funky --for classical strings! --syncopated bridge section around 1:59.

Comment: Thanks. Just listening to it on YouTube (and it sounds much better the on-hold thingy, haha).